# changing an asp control name/reference from c# backend

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am using jquery table addrow plugin to generate more of  the same fields (for a user o add more than one of the same type of data)

when a new field is added, control ID's are generated on the fly with a 1, 2, 3 etc at the end of the control for as many fields as added

This is my textbox

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="documentName1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="195px" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I reference it in my c# as documentName1. whatever
basically i want a way to change this textbox to be called 'documentName2' from c#

maybe there is a way to store it in asp as a variable ??

I tried documentName1 = documentName2 , documentName1.ID = "documentName2"
Tried creating a new textbox instance and named it documentName2 and then assigned it to documentName1. All these dont work

Help please ??

Comment: You want to change the ID of a control that is already created in your code-behind??

Comment: Yes, It is created in my asp page. I want my textbox to now be documentName2 (when a new row is added the name of that row is documentName2 but i dont see this from my asp page cuz it happens on the fly)

Comment: so when does the error occur and what is it - documentName1.ID = "documentName2" should do it

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I think the problem is in your logic to be honest.  I can't think of a reason you would ever need to change a control ID

Comment: it didnt give me an error but i couldnt get the data in that textbox when i tried to so figured i was doing it wrong. The plugin im using dynamically changes control names in that format so i was tring to reference them to store data.. I found a work around anyway. Thanks alot guys! :)